# Can we use a text file to import the SQL code in TM1 turbointegrator process?

Tags: cognos-tm1

I have saved the SQL code in the text file in a path (e.g. C: /docs/test.txt) and trying to read and execute it in Tm1 TI process.

Here's the code:

```
content vInFileName = 'c:\documents\code.txt';
s_SQL = open('vInFileName',read,In), repeat, read_line_to_codes(In,X),writef(" "), writef(X),nl, X=end_of_file,!, nl, close(In) ;
vOutFileName = 'c:\documents\output.txt'; 
ASCIIOUTPUT(vOutFileName, s_SQL);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO you should provide the code of what you have tried and a minimal, reproductible example for the community to help you

Comment: @ted I have tried the below code but not working
This one I was checking whether the code will read the file content

vInFileName = 'c:\documents\code.txt'; 

s_SQL =  
    open('vInFileName',read,In),
    repeat,
    read_line_to_codes(In,X),writef(" "),
    writef(X),nl,
    X=end_of_file,!,
    nl,
    close(In)

;

vOutFileName = 'c:\documents\output.txt'; 
ASCIIOUTPUT(vOutFileName, s_SQL);

Comment: Trademark capitalization; acronym capitalization; grammar; noise reduction; layout.

Comment: That doesn't seem like TM1 TI code.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes. Your code is not a Turbointegrator code though.

Try looking at IBM TM1's ODBC TI reference pages: [ODBC TurboIntegrator Functions](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSD29G_2.0.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.tm1_prism_gs.2.0.0.doc/c_odbcturbointegratorfunctions_n719eb.html)